# Read Gnome Shell Notifications

Tags: c, fedora, gnome-3, gnome-shell

I need to read the gnome-shell notifications to send an e-mail whenever event X happens (like a torrent was successfully downloaded). Is there a file or a callback that I can read/set in C code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very easy option would be to call the `notify-send` tool from your code. It is used like this:

```
notify-send [OPTION...] <SUMMARY> [BODY] - create a notification
```

For more information, see the accompanying man-page.

Edit: I first read this question wrong and thought you wanted to *send* notifications. For *reacting* to notifications, I would suggest writing a `gnome-shell` extension. There is already [an example extension](https://github.com/hackedbellini/Gnome-Shell-Notifications-Alert) that shows how to react to *all* notifications.

I am not aware of any callbacks for your own code, sorry. But you could probably roll your own notification callback via `DBUS`. See [the DBUS homepage](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus) for more details. In short, your shell extension could generate an appropriate `DBUS` message, to which your program then could react.

Sorry for my reading error :)

Comment: But there is a way to read a message send by another programm, like pidgin with a callback or something like that?

Comment: @EliasGranja Sorry, I misread your question initially and added some details just now.